# All MCP2518FD-based CAN FD boards won't work on low data rates

Tags: can-bus

MCP2518FD is a pretty common CAN FD controller used in many expansion HAT solutions for Raspberry PI (almost all of them are based on this Microchip family of CAN controllers).

The problem is: I never managed to make it work with bitrate switching and data bitrates slower than about 700kbps.

For example, this interface config works fine:

```
ifconfig can0 down && sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 100000 dbitrate 800000 restart-ms 1000 berr-reporting on fd on
```

This gives an error on **any** transmission:

```
ifconfig can0 down && sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 100000 dbitrate 700000 restart-ms 1000 berr-reporting on fd on
```

When the transmission reaches the bitrate switch point, the controller itself seeing its own bits on rx-pin, throws the error frame.
The regular (normal) bitrate can be anything, it doesn't change the result.

Back in the days there was no kernel-included driver for this (like we have mcp251xfd now), so the drivers were third-party, and I managed to make them work just disabling the thing named "transmission delay compensation" (which for some reason breaks things on low dbitrates) in source code and then recompiling and reinstalling them. Now the old drivers wont compile under recent Raspbian versions, and the built-in kernel ones aren't working for the same reason.

The bold statement is: I suppose that this is some kind of undocumented errata in the silicon (tried several chips from different lots) or a bug in standard kernel drivers.

**The question is: does anyone have MCP2518FD-based board, and the board works fine with dbitrates lower then 750000?**

If yes, maybe there are some ideas on what can go wrong in my case.

Transmission with no BRS: the transmission passes the arbitration phase, there is no data here, so after the arbitration here goes CRC and the rest of the transmission:
[image: Transmission with no BRS]

Transmission with BRS: after the BRS bit and a few bits of CRC in bitrate-switched rate (in this example it is of the same rate as the normal rate), the controller raises the error frame on its own transmission:
[image: Transmission with BRS]

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance resolve this?
I'm seeing similar issues with a MCP2518FD connected to a Rpi CM4. Works down to about 500 kbps (but need 250 kbps).

My initial findings was that the ACK bit stay active for too short time meaning the remote device keeps retransmitting the same frame (which is correctly received, just not ack'ed).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/131758)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).